# How does iTunes know what albums to associate with each album artwork file?

Tags: itunes, album-art

I have recently been trying to systematically extract album artwork from my iTunes library, such that I can use them elsewhere.

I understand that all the album artwork is stored in the `Album Artwork` folder, inside iTunes-specific `.itc2` files. I have researched and found that these files are simply wrappers for PNG, JPG, and RAW image data.

Which is fine - I can extract those images as I wish - however, I cannot determine *how* iTunes knows which `.itc2` file belongs to each album. For playlist artwork, I have found that the second part of the file's name is equal to the `Playlist Persistent ID` found under the corresponding playlist in the `iTunes Music Library.xml` file. Yet it seems the same is not true for *album* artwork - there is nothing like an "Album Persistent ID" parameter.

**So how does iTunes know which album each album artwork file belongs to?**

Comment: Are you sure a file belongs to *an album*? I think that each individual song has it's own artwork file. An album, in the physical-old-school sense of a CD or LP, is the same in iTunes as a Playlist- they are both a virtual group of arbitrary songs. As you've found, playlists can be albums, or groupings of non related songs, in which case the "playlist art" that I often see is 4 pieces of art from songs in that playlist.

Comment: Hmm, it's possible that the artwork belongs to a song instead, but I still have no idea how they're related. They don't seems to be associated via the songs's internal ID.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is copied into each song file, for two reasons: (1) When I add artwork to a whole album, a progress pop-up shows the song names one at a time; (2) if I copy a file from iTunes to another directory, it still has the album art as its icon.  It's such a waste of space, if a copy is kept elsewhere with pointers.